# WP_Query echoing arrays in different spots

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops

Hello I need to echo a WP_Query in different areas so I can add content between each render post title..

SO basically I want to manual breakout the posts so I can place them around static content. Hope this is making sense.

I want to do something like this. Please see my notes.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    $the_query->the_post();

    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; // first post title

        //echo 'some static content';

        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; //second post title

        //echo 'some more static content';

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array with all the static content:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$static_content = array ('content after first post','content after second post');

$counter = 0;

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    $the_query->the_post();

    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

    echo $static_content[$counter];

    $counter++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Can I do that with the posts? Because what I was wanting to do was to control the post around the content.

Something like: 
echo get_the_title[0].''.etc..;
Some Content
echo get_the_title[1].''.etc..;
Some More content
Some More Content again
echo get_the_title[2].''.etc..;

Comment: Yes, you can use the while-loop to add the titles to an array, then use them after the loop. `$titles[] = get_the_title()`, `echo content . $titles[0] . more-content . $titles[1]` etc.